# Replace a line of text in a file, with the contents of another file

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, docker, text-processing

I have two files, let's call them `foo.py` and `fixed_rule_map`. I need to:

- find the line in `foo.py` that contains the pattern `rule_map =` . It would be enough to find the pattern `rule_map`, if that's easier, but since there are more than one line in `foo.py` which contains `rule_map`, in this case I need to match only the first occurrence.
- substitute the line in `foo.py` with the contents of `fix_rule_map_in_foo` (which contains a single line of text).

For example, `foo.py` may look like this:

```
class example:
    """some useless text.
    
    """
    rule_map = {'greater': lambda x, y: x > y, 'less': lambda x, y: x < y}

    def __init__(self,
                rule=None,
                ):
        self._init_rule(rule)


    def _init_rule(self, rule):
        if rule not in self.rule_map and rule is not None:
            raise KeyError(f'rule must be greater, less or None, '
                           f'but got {rule}.')
        self.rule = rule
        if self.rule is not None:
            self.compare_func = self.rule_map[self.rule]
```

and I would like to correct it to this:

```
class example:
    """some useless text.
    
    """
    rule_map = {'greater': lambda x, y: (x if x is not None else -inf) > (y if y is not None else -inf), 'less': lambda x, y: (x if x is not None else -inf) < (y if y is not None else -inf)}

    def __init__(self,
                rule=None,
                ):
        self._init_rule(rule)


    def _init_rule(self, rule):
        if rule not in self.rule_map and rule is not None:
            raise KeyError(f'rule must be greater, less or None, '
                           f'but got {rule}.')
        self.rule = rule
        if self.rule is not None:
            self.compare_func = self.rule_map[self.rule]
```

thus `fixed_rule_map` would be a text file containing

```
    rule_map = {'greater': lambda x, y: (x if x is not None else -inf) > (y if y is not None else -inf), 'less': lambda x, y: (x if x is not None else -inf) < (y if y is not None else -inf)}
```

**Note** that since `foo.py` is a Python file, the substitution must preserve indentation.

The command that performs the substitution has to go in a Dockerfile, since the substitution must be performed when building the Docker image. Docker uses `/bin/sh` as an interpreter for RUN commands, rather than `/bin/bash`, which may be a problem if your solution uses `bash`. However, I think I could fix this by using a shell script `fix_rule_map_in_foo.sh`:

```
#! /bin/bash
FOO_PATH = /path/to/foo
<your_solution>
```

and adding this line in the Dockerfile:

```
RUN fix_rule_map_in_foo.sh
```

Comment: Something like this `awk -v fix="$(cat fix_rule_map_in_foo)" '/rule_map = / {$0 = fix}1' foo.py`

Comment: @Raffa sounds interesting. Can you write it as an answer and explain in detail the syntax of the command?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the sed editor's `r` command to read the contents of a file and insert them, deleting the original matching line after:

```
sed -e '/rule_map = /{r fix_rule_map_in_foo' -e 'd;}' foo.py
```

The new contents will be written to standard output by default, but GNU sed supports an in-place editing flag (`--in-place` or `-i`).

Since this doesn't involve any shell constructs, I *think* you can run it directly (although I don't use docker, so don't know for sure):

```
RUN sed -i.bak -e '/rule_map = /{r fix_rule_map_in_foo' -e 'd;}' foo.py
```

however you can put it in a POSIX shell script if you prefer.

Alternatively, using the non-stream editor `ed` (this **does** use shell constructs, so must be in a script):

```
#!/bin/sh

printf '%s\n' '/rule_map = /r fix_rule_map_in_foo' '-1d' 'wq' | ed -s foo.py
```

Comment: why  `sed -i.bak`? Shoudn't the command be `sed -i`?

Comment: it looks like `sed` in my Docker image supports the `-i` option, so this should work.

Answer (score 2):

You can set that single line contained in the file `fix_rule_map_in_foo` in a variable named e.g. `fix` with command substitution like so:

```
fix="$(cat fix_rule_map_in_foo)"
```

You can set the variable to a fixed string as well if you wish (*instead of reading that string from a file*) like so:

```
fix="The substitution string here"
```

Then pas that variable to `awk` so you can match the line and substitute it like so:

```
awk -v fix="$(cat fix_rule_map_in_foo)" '/rule_map = / {$0 = fix}1' foo.py
```

That will search for `rule_map =`  and replace the line that contains the match with the value of the variable `fix` and print all the lines(*after modification*) to the terminal ... you can redirect the output to a file if you wish with e.g. `>`.

If you wish to edit the file `foo.py` instead, then use the GNU awk like so:

```
gawk -i inplace -v fix="$(cat fix_rule_map_in_foo)" '/rule_map = / {$0 = fix}1' foo.py
```

Comment: The Docker image I'm using doesn't have `gawk`, but only `awk`. Isn't it possible to edit the file `foo.py` using `awk`?

Comment: Also, I made some edits to the question. Could you please have a look? Thanks. It's important that the substitution preserves the indentation, since `foo.py` is a Python script and indentation matters.

Comment: @DeltaIV Not natively but you can ether use command substitution like `echo $(awk -v fix="$(cat fix_rule_map_in_foo)" '/rule_map = / {$0 = fix}1' foo.py) > foo.py`   or ...

Comment: Write to a temp file then rename it overwriting the original file `awk -v fix="$(cat fix_rule_map_in_foo)" '/rule_map = / {$0 = fix}1' foo.py > tmpfile && mv tmpfile foo.py` ...

Comment: That said some versions of `awk` do that so test first `awk -i inplace -v fix="$(cat fix_rule_map_in_foo)" '/rule_map = / {$0 = fix}1' foo.py` ... might work.